# how do i solve Error dev webpack style hot loader js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i am new in native script, when i run this code

```
<template>
    <view class="container">
        <text class="text-color-primary">My Vue Native Apps</text>
    </view>
</template>
<style>
    .container{
        background-color:white;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content=center;
        flex:1;
    }
    .text-color-primary{
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

and theres error result:

```
ERROR in ./components/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader.js!../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/apply-css-loader.js!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-2!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/Home.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js):
CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\a\basic\components\components\Home.vue:11:0: Unknown word
```

helpmehh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to this issue on GitHub: [vue-loader not installed correctly](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1419)